# Meteor cant access .find() data

Tags: meteor

Hi I am trying to retrieve some data from a collection. I am finding the collection like so .

```
var myData = Product.find({ _id: id}).fetch();
```

OR

```
 var myData = Product.find({ _id: id});
```

which returns

```
[object Object]
```

If i try access the data I get undefined

```
myData.data._id
myData._id
myData.selling.t1
```

All undefined. Any ideas

**Class**

```
 import {
        Template
    } from 'meteor/templating';
    import {
        Meteor
    } from 'meteor/meteor';
    import {
        Product
    } from '../../../../../api/lists/Products.js';

    import './ProductSingle.html';


    if (Meteor.isClient) {

        var id;

        Template.ProductSingle.onCreated(function() {
            var self = this;
            self.autorun(() => {
                self.subscribe('product');
            });
            id = this.data._id;

        });



        Template.ProductSingle.onRendered(function() {
            var myData = Product.find({ _id: id}); // Need this to create instance
            console.log("this data" + myData.data._id);
            var container = document.getElementById(this.data.name + "Container");
            var hot = new Handsontable(container, { // Create Handsontable instance
                data: [[]],
                startRows: 2,
                startCols: 12,
                minCols: 12,
                minRows: 2,
                colHeaders: true,
                rowHeader: ['Selling Price', 'Purchase Price'],
                minSpareRows: 1,
                contextMenu: true,
                cells: function(row, col, prop, value) {
                var cellProperties = {
                    type: 'numeric',
                    format: '0.00'
                };
                cellProperties.renderer = rowRenderer;
                return cellProperties;
                }
                // afterChange: function(change, source) { // "change" is an array of arrays. 
                //     if (source !== "loadData") { // Don't need to run this when data is loaded
                //         for (i = 0; i < change.length; i++) { // For each change, get the change info and update the record
                //             var rowNum = change[i][0]; // Which row it appears on Handsontable
                //             var row = myData[rowNum]; // Now we have the whole row of data, including _id
                //             var key = change[i][1]; // Handsontable docs calls this "prop"
                //             var oldVal = change[i][2];
                //             var newVal = change[i][3];
                //             var setModifier = {
                //                 $set: {}
                //             }; // Need to build $set object
                //             setModifier.$set[key] = newVal; // So that we can assign 'key' dynamically using bracket notation of JavaScript object
                //            //MyCollection.update(row._id, setModifier);
                //         }
                //     }
                // }
            });

            function rowRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
                Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
                var rowId;
                switch(row) {
                    case 0:
                        //rowId = myData.sellingPrice.M;
                        //console.log(myData)
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        rowId = myData.purchasePrice;
                        break;
                }


                if (!value || value === '' || value == null) {
                    console.log(rowId+col)
                    //td.innerHTML = rowId+col;
                }
            }


            // Tracker.autorun(function() { // Tracker function for reactivity
            //     myData = Product.findOne({ _id: id}); // Tie in our data
            //     hot.loadData(myData);
            //     console.log(myData);

            // });

        });
    }
```

I am quiet confused right now why would I not be able to access the object data. If i can access it on the template side

Comment: Do you have a publication for your Products collection? Also, `Product.find()` returns a cursor while `Product.find().fetch()` returns an array. Hence, `myData._id` while be `unefined`, what you want is `myData[0]._id` for example. Alternatively, you can use `Product.findOne()` which returns a single object from the collection.

Comment: Hey there I manged to get it working by using a Tracker . Yes I do have it published . Thanks for the reply